# How to extract data from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I am using Google Script to fetch an url that returns me the following JSON object:

```
[
    {
        "rsid":"op-bigideas",
        "site_title":"Big Ideas",
        "evars":[
            {
                "name":"Tracking Code",
                "type":"text_string",
                "id":"trackingcode",
                "expiration_type":"week",
                "expiration_custom_days":"1",
                "allocation_type":"most_recent_last"
            },
            {
                "name":"Custom eVar 1",
                "description":"",
                "type":"text_string",
                "enabled":false,
                "id":"evar1",
                "expiration_type":"visit",
                "expiration_custom_days":1,
                "allocation_type":"most_recent_last"
            }
        ]
     }
  ]
```

How can I extract the `name` property from `evars` using `javascript` with `Google Apps Script`?

This is the code that returns me the JSON object:

```
var elements = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options));
```

I already tried the following but only receiving `undefined` message:

1.

```
  for(var elem in elements) {
    Logger.log(elements[elem]['evars'].name);
  }
```

2.

```
  for(var elem in elements) {
    Logger.log(elements[elem].evars.name);
  }
```

3.

```
var newData = JSON.parse(elements);
Logger.log(newData.evars.name)
```

Comment: Point of education: There is no thing as a JSON object.  Once you parse the data you have a JavaScript object or an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the values of the `name` properties. This code will log the `name` properties:

```
for (var elem in elements) {
  for (var evar in elements[elem].evars) {
    Logger.log(elements[elem].evars[evar].name);
  }
}
```

This will output:

```
"Tracking Code"
"Custom eVar 1"
```

Comment: I added only 1 object to question, but the JSON contains more than 10 objects and I need to log the `name` property for all of them...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple `name` properties for each element, so I think you want to map twice:

```
elements.map(function(elt) {
    return !elt.evars ? [] : elt.evars.map(function(evar) {
        return evar.name;
    });
});
```

This will give you an array of arrays; the outer array is the elements, each of which contains an array of the names.  For your example, this will be:

```
[
    ["Tracking Code", "Custom eVar 1"]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (var elem in elements[0].evars) {
  Logger.log(elements[0].evars[elem].name);
}
```